# How to print just the names in a tuple

Tags: python

- Hello I am fairly new to python and wondering how to write a function old_enough(students) that takes a list of (name, age) tuples, where name is a string and age is an int, and returns a list of just the names of students who are old enough to vote. The names must be in the same order as in the students list.

Test Code:

```
students = [('Mary', 23), ('Peter', 17),
    ('Tao', 18), ('Chinnie', 19), ('Angus', 5)]
print(old_enough(students))
```

Result:

```
['Mary', 'Tao', 'Chinnie']
```

I thought this was a dictionary question but now I am confused. Thank you.

Comment: Iterate with a for-loop through the tuples and add name for each with appropriate age (check with "if") to a result list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in many ways, but perhaps the simplest and most concise is using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

E.g.

```
def old_enough(students):
    return [name for name, age in students if age > 17]
```

Which can be less concisely expressed using a `for` loop as:

```
def old_enough(students):
    voters = []
    for name, age in students:
        if age > 17:
            voters.append(name)
    return voters
```

My preference is for the list comprehension, I think it is more pythonic and readable.

Comment: Can you  also do it with a for loop?

Comment: Yes, see edit. I would have a strong preference for the list comprehension version though

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I personally understand the for a loop a lot better than list comprehension version but I am trying to transition to coding with list comprehension